# ios array to dictionary or to array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, dictionary

Im getting a JSON response to my app [Twitter web service], is a string, but for example the object at index 0 is:

```
es array en:0, tiene {
contributors = "<null>";
coordinates = "<null>";
"created_at" = "Thu Aug 04 23:26:05 +0000 2011";
favorited = 0;
geo = "<null>";
id = 99259843982016513;
"id_str" = 99259843982016513;
"in_reply_to_screen_name" = "<null>";
"in_reply_to_status_id" = "<null>";
"in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "<null>";
"in_reply_to_user_id" = "<null>";
"in_reply_to_user_id_str" = "<null>";
place = "<null>";
"possibly_sensitive" = 0;
"retweet_count" = 0;
retweeted = 0;
source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/tweetbutton\" rel=\"nofollow\">Tweet Button</a>";
text = "Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Freelance Workers http://t.co/yaW1RHp";
truncated = 0;
user =     {
    "contributors_enabled" = 0;
    "created_at" = "Mon Jul 13 19:39:31 +0000 2009";
    "default_profile" = 0;
    "default_profile_image" = 0;
    description = "My goal is to enable the brain computer interfaces to use the possibilities of mobile platforms for robotics and physical computing";
    "favourites_count" = 0;
    "follow_request_sent" = "<null>";
    "followers_count" = 92; ...
```

so there are like 17 objects for my array [for each twitt], so how can I decompose those objects into further arrays or a dictionary?

I specifaclly want the text key

```
text = "Apple vs Samsung tablets [haha and Samsung is an Apple hardware provider!!]\nhttp://t.co/rvv43Hy";
```

thanks a lot

Comment: The (first) "text" value is easy since it's in the outer dictionary.  Just use `objectForKey:@"text"`.  (But you're showing a different value for "text", so it may be a more deeply embedded version.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may already be a parser built for this, but if not I think you'll find the following method useful.

```
NSArray *strings = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

It returns an array of strings with (in this case) ";" as a delimiter.

> {contributors = "" , coordinates = "", ...}

You can them separate them further:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *s in strings)
{
    NSArray *keyValue = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *value = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];
    [dict setValue:value forKey:key];
}
```

There does seem to be some extra data at the start of the response, you might have to strip this off first.

Comment: The OP's data is an NSDictionary containing another NSDictionary.  It's he height of foolishness to attempt to parse it using `componentsSeparateByStrings`.

Answer (score 2):

You would, eg, extract the "user" object from your outer dictionary and assign that to an NSDictionary variable.  Then you can extract, say, "default_profile" from the second dictionary.

One could probably write a simple "path navigator" tool that would access an individual entity via "path notation" without having to explicitly extract the component pieces, but I don't know of a "canned" one.

Answer (score 1):

just in case someone else is looking for this, I ended up using the

open-source JSON Framework by Stig Brautaset.
with its parser, 
and followed some instructions f[rom here](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c)